# PHP check if $_POST is empty in php 5+

Tags: php, login-script

I want to try to check if a $_POST array is empty but I have not found any solution in 2 days of googling and searching on youtube.
here is my basic code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['username']) and $_POST['password']){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    foreach($username as $user){
        if(empty($_POST[$user])){
            $error = "you need to fill in your username";
        }
    }
    foreach($password as $pass){
        if(empty($_POST[$pass])){
            $error = "you need to fill in your password";
        }
    }
    if(isset($error)){
        echo $error;

        ?>
        <br> <br>
    <?php
    }
        }
```

thank you all

Comment: Could you reformulate your question ? The isset test passes even though the index is empty ? Could you join the error message ?

Comment: `and $_POST['password']` doesn't do much. `foreach($password as $pass){
        if(empty($_POST[$pass]))` how many password are there? Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and show your HTML form.

Comment: Are `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` arrays? ie. does your form have `name="username[]"`?

Comment: I also hope you're storing a "hash" and not as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

To check if `$_POST` is empty or not all you need to do is

```
if(empty($_POST)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code is peculiar:

```
foreach($username as $user){
    if(empty($_POST[$user])){
        $error = "you need to fill in your username";
    }
}
```

It's saying to get every array element of `$username`. Then you check if the element is empty. If `$username` has 0 elements then it will never get inside that loop. You will not see that error message. However, there's a deeper concern here. This code is written expecting `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']` to be arrays. That almost certainly is not the case.

Instead, you can use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if( !array_key_exists('username',$_POST) )
{
    $error = "you need to fill in your username";
}
```

As a side security concern, I really hope you're not storing password information as plain text through `$_POST`. You don't want that information to be intercepted by any party.

Comment: *This code is written expecting $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] to be arrays. That almost certainly is not the case.* not true at all. I have enough posts that are arrays. Not passwords and usernames but it's not that unlikely.

Comment: Having an array in `$_POST` is to be expected. Having a username and password come in as an array of usernames and passwords? That's very unlikely to me. Not impossible, but it seems like something is wrong design-wise if that's the case, y'know?

Comment: the $error variable does give away that there is something wrong design-wise. I give you that.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to try to check if a $_POST array is empty

The problem with your code is this part:

```
if(empty($_POST[$user])){
```

You're misunderstanding the function [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

You need to have an if like this:

```
if(isset($user)){
```

*This is all based on you wanting to check if a value of the array is empty.* If you want anything else, you're not being clear enough at all.

You're already checking if the arrays are empty with this part:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) and $_POST['password']){
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you're dealing with an array of usernames and passwords. Maybe is this what you're looking for:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) and $_POST['password']){

    $error_msg = "Please provide username and password!";

    if(isset($_POST['username']))
        $username = $_POST['username'];

    if(isset($_POST['password']))
        $password = $_POST['password'];

    if( !isset($username) || !isset($password) )
        echo $error_msg;
    else{
        //Do something ?
    }
}
```

Anyway, you should be using `isset` to check if the variable exists and you can use `empty` to check if the variable is empty.

Comment: May be a better method, but using proper bracing techniques may avoid possible havoc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if(!empty($_POST['username']))` (not empty), `if(isset($_POST['username']))` or simply `if($_POST['username'])`, i.e.:

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) and !empty($_POST['password'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
}
```

Note: `empty()` is the safest way to check if the `POST` var contains a value.

---

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
}
```

Note: `isset()` will return `true` with just  spaces.

---

In order to simplify your code, I would suggest the following:

```
if($_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
}
```

Note: it will also return `true` with just  spaces.